# CLLocationManager didUpdateToLocation:, on which thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nstimer, cllocationmanager

I'm currently trying to implement a timeout feature on a `CLLocationManager` delegate call.
Here's the code:

```
- (void)checkInAt:(UALocation *)location timeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout {
    NSDate *tickDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeout];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.timeout = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:tickDate interval:0 target:self selector:@selector(timedOut:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    @synchronized (self.timeout) {
        // Todo what if the timer fires right now?
        // Is it even feasible? On what thread is CLLocationManager operating?
        if (self.timeout.isValid) {
            [self.timeout invalidate];
        }
        else {
            // Timed out
            return;
        }
    }

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    // Do the actual check in
}

- (void)timedOut:(NSTimer *)timer {
    @synchronized (timer) {
        if (!timer.isValid) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you read the code, you probably stumbled upon my questions already.

1. Is there a better way (= already existing in `CLLocationManager`) to implement such a timeout?
2. On what thread does the `CLLocationManager` call methods of its delegate?
3. If it's not the main thread, I could potentially have a problem where the comments highlight it. How can I circumvent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple add breakpoint in method and on the left side in the xcode you will see which thread is.

First thread is main thread

[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact, the delegate call is made on the main thread. Thank you for your valuable input.